# How to solve ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR which occurs only when editing page through elementor

Tags: wordpress, element

I am working on a WordPress site and using Elementor page builder. Initially, I created a page and published it, but after some time I wanted to make some changes so I clicked on edit with elementor and it shows ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR. However, I can see the page working fine but I can't make any changes. I am able to edit a new page or other pages but not that page. Please someone help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue
Add this to your .htaccess

```
# BEGIN Line too long fix
<IfModule mod_substitute.c>
SubstituteMaxLineLength 20M
</IfModule>
# END Line too long fix
```